# Stripe token works on direct charge but not through the platform

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

this is a Stripe specific question that I'm unable to figure out.

Initially I had my stripe connected settings on direct charge, that means the platform takes it cut but the charge goes directly to the recipient. Our problem with that is that stripe takes their fee from the user, and we want it to take the fee from our side.

Thus we need to charge through the platform.

Now when I test my code with a direct charge it works, however when I change it to through the platform it says that:

```
No such token: tok_16lFgxDVBtbPPV
```

here's my code for charging directly (this works):

```
  token = Stripe::Token.create( { customer: customer.stripe_customer_id }, stripe_account: @user.uid)

  Stripe::Charge.create({
    amount: total_amount,
    currency: 'usd',
    source: token,
    application_fee: platform_fee},
    stripe_account: @user.uid
  )
```

now here's my code for charging through the platform:

```
  token = Stripe::Token.create( { customer: customer.stripe_customer_id }, stripe_account: @user.uid)
  Stripe::Charge.create({
    amount: total_amount,
    currency: 'usd',
    source: token,
    application_fee: platform_fee,
    destination: @user.uid
  })
```

can the problem be that the token should be created differently when charged through the platform?

Here's the documentation for easy reference: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payments-fees

Comment: This error often occurs when a token has been consumed. The stripe `token` are used only once in lifetime before expiration

Comment: yes, but as you see I do generate a new token for every single time, that's why I'm confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a token using `token = Stripe::Token.create( { customer: customer.stripe_customer_id }, stripe_account: @user.uid)` the token is created in the stripe account of the user. That works fine when you create the charge in the user's account (like in your first example). However in your second example, the charge is created in your account. When the charge is in your account there is actually no need to create a new token as you can just charge the customer and set the destination.

This should do it:

```
 Stripe::Charge.create({
    amount: total_amount,
    currency: 'usd',
    customer: customer.stripe_customer_id,
    application_fee: platform_fee,
    destination: @user.uid
  })
```